# How to disable disk read cache?

Tags: windows, cache, hard-drive

Is there a way to disable disk read cache on Windows?
Disks are connected to a Dell PERC6/i controller.
Is there a way to disable the controller's cache too?

Comment: Could I possibly ask why? Do you suspect the cache is faulty?

Comment: I just want to test its effect on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the cache policy on the controller in the properties of the controller. You'll need to have Dell OpenManage Server Administrator installed in order to do this. There may be a way in DOMSA to change the disk cache policy as well.

Comment: Where do I change the properties of the controller?
In Windows I saw only write caching policy, and in DOMSA I saw nothing about cache.

Comment: In DOMSA expand the storage node in the left frame and keep expanding until you see the Virtual Disks. Select the Virtual disks node in the left frame and you should see your virtual disk in the right frame. Each virtual disk should have a Tasks drop down where you can select the option to "Change Policy".

If you don't see it there, you can configure it using the PERC BIOS utility. Here's a link to the PERC6 documentation:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/PERC6/en/PDF/en_ug.pdf